# Multiple choice questions in exam

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory

In a country-level placement exam, there are 10 multiple-choice questions, each with 4 equivalent possible replies.
What is the minimum number of students taking this exam, so that it is *always* possible to find at least 2 sets with at least 9 same replies? All questions must be answered (and we assume that they are answered at random, that is, without any previous knowledge of the subjects).

My thoughts:
All possible different sets of replies are $4^{10}$.
If we get $4^{9}+1$, do we ensure we will have at least 9 same sets?

Comment: The current wording suggests that the answer is _two_.

Comment: Apologies, I made an edit in the wording. The question is about exactly the same replies in 9 out of 10 questions.

Comment: I think your logic is correct; we can pick any 9 questions to regard. One can take a simpler case to understand; say take 3 questions requiring 2 sets with 2 same replies. Then we can check manually. Then this principle can be extended to the given problem/

Comment: It only takes two for it to be possible (e.g. it is possible that student A submits the same answers as student B and thus allowing that _possibility_).

Comment: Use generalized pigeonhole priciple

Comment: I would consider adding a coding theory tag to this question. (It can be interpreted as asking for the maximum number of code words of length 10 over a 4-character alphabet such that the minimum distance is 2).

Comment: @paw88789 Whenever you feel a tag should be added, it is perfectly valid to add it yourself. I agree coding theory applies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, the minimum number is $4^9+1$. You can prove this works using the pigeonhole principle, with $4^9$ holes corresponding to the answers to the first $9$ questions.

To prove this is the minimum, you need to find a set of $4^9$ tests where no two agree on $8$ answers. From the pigeonhole argument, you know that every possible string of $4^9$ answers for the first $9$ questions must appear exactly once. You just need to choose the last answer for each of these in such a way that when any two answer sequences agree in $8$ places, their $10^{th}$ answers do not agree. Addition $\pmod 4$ is one way to accomplish this...

Comment: Please consider saying a bit more about your last line regarding addition mod 4.